# Is this passage correct?

Tags: dirac-delta, kronecker-delta

How to justify the following passage

$$\int_{j-1}^j \int_{k-1}^{k} \delta (t-\tau) \, dt \, d\tau=\delta_{jk}$$

$j, k\in \mathbb{Z}\; t, \tau \in \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the delta is on the line $t=\tau$. If the cell $[k,k-1]\times[j,j-1]$ doesn't contain that line, the integral is $0$. So now consider the integral

$$\int_{j-1}^j \int_{k-1}^k \delta(t-\tau)dtd\tau = \int_{j-1}^j H(t-\tau)\Bigr|_{k-1}^k d\tau$$ $$ = \int_{k-1}^k H(k-\tau) - H(k-1-\tau) d\tau = \int_{k-j}^{k-j+1} H(\tau')-H(\tau'-1)d\tau'$$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. Notice that the integrand is a box of height $1$ between $0\leq \tau' \leq 1$. If $j\neq k$, then the integral integrates over $0$. We only integrate over the nonzero portion of the box when the limits of integration are $0$ and $1$, i.e. $j=k$. Thus the integral evaluates to $\delta_{jk}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what if last integration is performed for 'limit cases' such as between $-1$ and $0$ or between $1$ and $2$, in $0$ and in $1$ integrand is nonzero

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta I already explained what happened in my post. Read it again. If you still don't understand, graph the integrand to see what I mean.

Comment: Graph of the integrand is clear to me, but still Heaviside step function admit a value of $1$ (or $1/2$ depending on how it is defined) at $0$, thus an integration performed between $-1$ and $0$ will comprehend that nonzero value, it's not clear to me what does happen in that case

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta integrals are areas. The area under a point is $0$.

Comment: I don't get it, what about integration of delta dirac itself? That is also a point

Comment: Ok, i eventually come up with the following prospective: the area under a point might not be $0$ but something infinitely small with respect to the value of the function in that point, this would explain the case of delta dirac integration, its integral is in fact $1$ (which is infinitely small with respect to the value of the function which is $+\infty$), and also it would explain the present situation, setting for the integral an infinitely small value with respect to the value of $1$, thus something very close to $0$ and thus negligible